# JSXGraph in Moodle: How to use MathJax for text

Tags: moodle, mathjax, jsxgraph

I use JSXGraph in Moodle and would like to render text with MathJax. Could someone provide an example of how this can be done? I have tried all kinds of combinations I could think of based on these sources:
https://jsxgraph.org/wiki/index.php/Using_MathJax
https://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/Text.html#useMathJax

Comment: You can see a working example with MathJax v3 at https://jsfiddle.net/uvp3mcf7/

Comment: I have actually already seen that example. But it wouldn't work in Moodle. Has this been tested with Moodle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the MathJax filter from Moodle, the order of the filters is important. Here is a link: https://github.com/jsxgraph/moodle-filter_jsxgraph/blob/master/README.md#using-mathjax-within-the-board
You can also find an example there.